# Creating a Materialized view with fast refresh and on Demand option

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, materialized-view

```
create materialized view XXARG_GOKU
AS 
select 
XDR.GLOBAL_ID
XDR.PARTY_ID,
XDR.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
XDU.CITY_CODE,
XDU.STD_CODE,
XDU.PIN_CODE_SERIAL_NO
from XXARG_DUMMY XDU, XXARG_DRAGON XDR
where
XDR.PIN_CODE_SERIAL_NO=XDU.PIN_CODE_SERIAL_NO;
```

I need a query for creating fast refresh with on demand option. I have already created MLOG$_XXARG_DUMMY and MLOG$_XXARG_DRAGON mlog tables for it.

Please note: the above query is for creating a Materialised view and I'm using oracle 10g DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Joins Only
>
> Defining queries for materialized views with joins only and no aggregates have the following restrictions on fast refresh:
>
> They cannot have `GROUP BY` clauses or aggregates.
>
> Rowids of all the tables in the FROM list must appear in the `SELECT` list of the query.
>
> Materialized view logs must exist with rowids for all the base tables in the `FROM` list of the query.

[Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Joins Only](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/basicmv.htm#i1007007)

**Example:**

```
SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON XXARG_DUMMY with rowid;       

Materialized view log created.

SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON XXARG_DRAGON with rowid;  

Materialized view log created.

SQL> create materialized view XXARG_GOKU
BUILD IMMEDIATE 
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
AS 
select 
XDU.rowid as XDU_rowid, XDR.rowid as XDR_rowid, 
XDR.GLOBAL_ID
XDR.PARTY_ID,
XDR.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
XDU.CITY_CODE,
XDU.STD_CODE,
XDU.PIN_CODE_SERIAL_NO
from XXARG_DUMMY XDU, XXARG_DRAGON XDR
where
XDR.PIN_CODE_SERIAL_NO=XDU.PIN_CODE_SERIAL_NO;
```